# Why can't I receive the body from a POST request even though it is returned in Postman?

Tags: javascript, flask, https, fetch

I am using the `fetch()` API in JavaScript to retrieve information from my flask backend server. I test the same URL and endpoint in postman, and I receive the response body. However, when I perform the same POST through `fetch()` and process the Response using `async/await`, I get `body: undefined` on the client side. Below is the code:

```
const result = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/auth`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: newUserBasicString, // some payload
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

`BACKEND_URL` is a forwarded ngrok https url. Why am I receiving no body?

Comment: What do you get instead? What do you when you inspect it using the Network tab of your browser's inspector?

Comment: You are missing another await  ...  `const data = await result.json()`. If that's not working check `result.ok` and `result.status`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, that worked! If you make it a response, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to handle the data returned by the fetch api, as be default it does not know how to handle the body. If you want to do it inline this should return what you want.

```js
const result = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/auth`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: newUserBasicString, // some payload
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
      }).then(response => response.json()) 
      // .json() for application/json response
      // .text() for application/text response
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Correct answer, but @charlietfi gave a better answer, with better troubleshooting.